# Reordering smart playlist with JXA (AppleScript JS with iTunes)

Tags: macos, applescript, javascript-automation

I am trying to make an AppleScript (in JS) that will reorder a smart playlist.

I can currently reorder a non-smart playlist with `track.move({to: playlist});` (so I can move any track within the playlist to the bottom), but that doesn't seem to work on a smart playlist because I get this error; `Error: File permission error`. It makes sense because you can't just add tracks to a smart playlist; its contents are based on a set of rules.

Is there a way to reorder a smart playlist?

Comment: Smart Playlists are completely owned by iTunes, they cannot be altered by any outside access.

Comment: Damn that really sucks. Thanks though, I'll have to find a different way

Comment: The only way that I have devised is to make a copy of the tracks in a Smart Playlist, create a User Playlist, and manipulate from there.  Clunky, but once it is automated, it works.